# Insertar PDF a MySQL a través de Windows Forms C++

Tags: c++, windows-forms

buenas tardes con una consulta. Llevo ya varios días buscando y he visto algunos video pero en C# y he intentado modificar a C++ algunas cosas pero nunca funciona, mi pregunta es:
Necesito un botón (que usa formularios de Windows en Visual Studio C ++) mediante el cual, cuando se presiona, se abre el explorador de archivos y el usuario puede seleccionar un archivo pdf. ¿Cómo almaceno ese archivo pdf en una base de datos MySQL?
Muchas gracias!